# What is the most efficient way of storing data read from a socket to be read by another thread?

Tags: c#, sockets

So I have a class using high speed I/O completion port sockets. The protocol of the data I am receiving has a 17 byte header, and a variable data payload which is specified in the header, so instead of calling ReceiveAsync individually for each header and the payload I am just grabbing up to a 1024 byte buffer chunk instead to save cpu usage.

However, I'm not sure what the best way of storing this data is? It has to be in order, and I want a separate thread to do the processing without having any threading or performance issues.

Should I be looking at a memorystream or something along those lines?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store it. And don't use another thread to read it. I would use the same thread to deserialize it into something more usable. Then queue it in another thread and let the IOCP thread continue with it's processing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store it. Have the other thread read it when it needs it.